# Best Way To Dynamically Achieve Offset and Limit Without Multiple Queries To The Database?

Tags: php, mysql, refactoring

I originally had a lightbox that once opened simply fetched all brands from a database which were in a list. The problem is that this list can be quite long so I split the brands out into lists of 10 and floated them left so that they filled the lightbox horizontally rather than vertically since there are around 40 brands.

The initial problem with my code is that it won't cover if suddenly, another 10 brands are added to the database since my code doesn't account for them.

The other problems are that I feel disgusted with myself having used multiple queries so I was wondering if anyone could offer any pointers about how to achieve the below with a bit more elegance and efficiency:

```
$sql2 = "SELECT page_id, name, url
             FROM " . DBTABLE_SITEMAP ."
             WHERE parent_id=$frames
             AND isActive=1
             AND isDeleted=0
             ORDER BY position ASC
             LIMIT 10";

$result2 = mysql_query($sql2, $db_conn);

if (mysql_num_rows($result2) > 0) {
    echo '<ol class="subnav-glasses">';

    while ($myrow2 = mysql_fetch_array($result2)) {
        $this_sub_page_id   = $myrow2["page_id"];
        $this_sub_name      = htmlentities($myrow2["name"]);
        $this_sub_url       = $myrow2["url"];


        echo "\n<li><a href=\"$this_sub_url\" title=\"$this_sub_name\">$this_sub_name</a>";                                
        echo '</li>';
    }
    echo "</ol>";
}


$sql3 = "SELECT page_id, name, url
             FROM " . DBTABLE_SITEMAP ."
             WHERE parent_id=$sitemap_designer_frames
             AND isActive=1
             AND isDeleted=0
             ORDER BY position ASC
             LIMIT 10
             OFFSET 10";

$result3 = mysql_query($sql3, $db_conn);

if (mysql_num_rows($result3) > 0) {
    echo '<ol class="subnav-glasses">';

    while ($myrow3 = mysql_fetch_array($result3)) {
        $this_sub_page_id   = $myrow3["page_id"];
        $this_sub_name      = htmlentities($myrow3["name"]);
        $this_sub_url       = $myrow3["url"];


        echo "\n<li><a href=\"$this_sub_url\" title=\"$this_sub_name\">$this_sub_name</a>";                                
        echo '</li>';
    }
    echo "</ol>";
}


$sql4 = "SELECT page_id, name, url
             FROM " . DBTABLE_SITEMAP ."
             WHERE parent_id=$sitemap_designer_frames
             AND isActive=1
             AND isDeleted=0
             ORDER BY position ASC
             LIMIT 10
             OFFSET 20";

$result4 = mysql_query($sql4, $db_conn);

if (mysql_num_rows($result4) > 0) {
    echo '<ol class="subnav-glasses">';

    while ($myrow4 = mysql_fetch_array($result4)) {
        $this_sub_page_id   = $myrow4["page_id"];
        $this_sub_name      = htmlentities($myrow4["name"]);
        $this_sub_url       = $myrow4["url"];


        echo "\n<li><a href=\"$this_sub_url\" title=\"$this_sub_name\">$this_sub_name</a>";                                
        echo '</li>';
    }
    echo "</ol>";
}


    $sql5 = "SELECT page_id, name, url
             FROM " . DBTABLE_SITEMAP ."
             WHERE parent_id=$sitemap_designer_frames
             AND isActive=1
             AND isDeleted=0
             ORDER BY position ASC
             LIMIT 10
             OFFSET 30";

$result5 = mysql_query($sql5, $db_conn);

if (mysql_num_rows($result5) > 0) {
    echo '<ol class="subnav-glasses">';

    while ($myrow5 = mysql_fetch_array($result5)) {
        $this_sub_page_id   = $myrow5["page_id"];
        $this_sub_name      = htmlentities($myrow5["name"]);
        $this_sub_url       = $myrow5["url"];


        echo "\n<li><a href=\"$this_sub_url\" title=\"$this_sub_name\">$this_sub_name</a>";                                
        echo '</li>';
    }
    echo "</ol>";
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some pseudo-code for you:

```
$sql2 = "SELECT page_id, name, url
         FROM " . DBTABLE_SITEMAP ."
         WHERE parent_id=$frames
         AND isActive=1
         AND isDeleted=0
         ORDER BY position ASC";

$result2 = mysql_query($sql2, $db_conn);

$i=0;
while ($myrow = mysql_fetch_array($result2))
{
  if ($i % 10 === 0)
  {
     if ($i > 0)
       echo "</ol>";

     echo "<ol>";
  }

  echo "<li>dsoajda</li>";

  $i++;
}

if ($i > 0)
  echo "</ol>";
```

Comment: thanks, it's almost there but not quite - here the html output I'm getting: http://jsfiddle.net/3mqKP/1/